# JUnit - writing tests

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am currently learning how to write tests to Java-code with JUnit.

Is the setup of the tests and syntax of this test okay? And should I keep all test-methods for one class in the same test-class?

Hope somebody can give some feedback!

```
public class HotelTest {

Hotel hotel;
int id1=0; 
int id2=0;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    hotel = new Hotel();
    this.id1 = hotel.registerRoom(5, "lowpriceroom", 200);
    this.id2 = hotel.registerRoom(3, "qualityroom", 300);

}
@After
public void tearDown(){
    hotel.hotelRooms.clear();

}

@Test
public void testRegisterRoom() {
    System.out.println(hotel.hotelRooms);
    assertTrue(hotel.hotelRooms.size() == 2);
    assertEquals(200, hotel.hotelRooms.get(id1).getPrice());
    assertEquals(3, hotel.hotelRooms.get(id2).getNumberOfPeople()); 

}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testExceptionWrongRoom() {
    hotel.registerRoom(3, "wrongRoom", 200);
}
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testExceptionTooManyPeople() {
    hotel.registerRoom(11, "lowpriceroom", 200);
}
```

This is the method i am testing:

```
    static HashMap<Integer, Room> hotelRooms = new HashMap<Integer, Room>();


        public int registerRoom(int numberOfPeople, String roomtype, int price){
                //Checking for illegal input
                if(numberOfPeople > 10){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error! Too many persons!"); 
                }
                if(roomtype == "lowpriceroom" ){
                    Lowpriceroom newRoom = new Lowpriceroom(numberOfPeople, price);
                    hotelRooms.put(newRoom.getID(), newRoom);
                    return newRoom.getID();
                }
                else if(roomtype == "qualityroom" ){
                    Qualityroom newRoom = new Qualityroom(numberOfPeople, price);
                    hotelRooms.put(newRoom.getID(), newRoom);
                    return newRoom.getID();
                }
                else{
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error! Not valid roomtype!");

               }
```

Comment: All looks good. Though you should never test string equality using `==`. Use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests to review "real" code should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Honestly, I dont agree with @killjoy here. It is not such a good idea to do so much setup in your setup method. Instead, each test case should do the *relevant* setup itself for example. You could also question if you should be using 3 asserts in one test.

Comment: @GhostCat  Should I write the relevant setup inside each test case instead then? And should I still use the setUp() and tearDown() methods for some of the declarations?

Comment: @GhostCat if you are going to suggest a user post code on another site please send them to the Help center of that page, so that they know the rules of that site, Code Review's is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: The idea of tests is that they quickly lead you to the source of the problem. This means: when a test fails, ideally, you only need to read the test itself to understand what it does. In your case, one has to scroll up to the setup method. That is not helpful. On the other hand, you dont want to repeat 10 lines of setup code in each test. This is about balancing different requirements. Beyond that: when that test ends, the `Hotel` object is lost anyway. There is no value from having a teardown method that calls clear on an object that is thrown away immediately afterwards!

Comment: And for the record: when you want to send a comment to somebody else (and you are not directly below that comment, you have to use the @ user syntax). I wasnt notified of your comment to me, only user @JohnStark saw that (I guess).

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for your answers, it became more clear now! :))